# socket.getfqdn() returns unexpected result

Tags: python, sockets

On my linux machine, when I execute `socket.getfqdn()` in python shell, I receive such a result `some_ip_address.static.midfase.com`, while the result is expected to be `.xxx.mydomain.com`.

On other machines it works perfect.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Maybe the other machines have an entry in `/etc/hosts` that customizes the result.

Comment: I've checked.
All entries are identical.

Comment: Every IP has a different FQDN. Why would you expect the same result on different machines?

Comment: I know that. Maybe my question was not written clearly.
I'm expecting not the same, but identical results.
for example 1st machine: xxx.yyy.com
                     2nd machine: zzz.yyy.com

Comment: You need to talk to your ISP about getting a correct reverse DNS entry for your machine.

Comment: You're just getting their default for your static IP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your machine must have `fqdn` name in `/etc/hosts`.

My machine has `fqdn` entry as:

```
#filename: /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 xxxx.yyy.com my-local-machine localhost
```

When I run python:

```
python -c "import socket; print socket.getfqdn()"
xxxx.yyy.com
```

I get `fqdn`.